# Angular Modal Service Controller dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using OcLazyLoad to load controller in router.
Here is snippet of my router.

```
.state("admin.report_draft", {
                url: "/report_draft",
                template: "<Redirect state='admin' page='report_draft'>",
                controller: "DraftReportController",
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                            name: 'MetronicApp',
                            insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                            files: [
                                'js/controllers/EditReportModalController.js',
                                'js/controllers/DraftReportController.js',
                                '../bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css',
                                '../bower_components/angular-chips/dist/main.css'
                            ]
                        });
                    }],
                },
                data: {pageTitle: 'Draft Reports'},
            })
```

EditReportModalController.js:

```
angular.module('MetronicApp').controller('EditReportModalController', function($scope, params){

    $scope.selectedReport = params;

    var url = '/admin/report/' + params.id;
    var sendModalRequest = function(url, method, data) {
        djangoAuth.request({
            method: method,
            url: url,
            data: data
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
        $state.reload();
        close(null, 200);
    };

    $scope.saveChanges = function(published){
        params['published'] = published;
        sendModalRequest('PUT', url, params);
    };

    console.log($scope.selectedReport);

});
```

Inside DraftReportController, I called ModalService to display modal.

DraftReportController.js:

```
angular.module('MetronicApp').controller('DraftReportController', function($scope, $state, djangoAuth, configService, FileUploader, ModalService, EditReportModalController){
            ....

            $scope.editDraft = function(report){
                    ModalService.showModal({
                        templateUrl: "views/modals/edit_report_draft.html",
                        controller: "EditReportModalController",
                        input:{
                            report: report
                        }
                    }).then(function(modal){
                        modal.element.modal();
                    })
                };
            ....
```

Here I am getting error:

> Unknown provider: EditReportModalControllerProvider <-
>   EditReportModalController <- DraftReportController

It seems EditReportModalController can not be resolved as dependency.
Would you like to help me? How can I have EditReportModalController inside DraftReportController as dependency?